# Is it Possible to publish two Websites, one in JSP and another in ASP.net with same domain name?

Tags: web-hosting

I want to publish two different websites one in JSP and another in ASP.net with same domain name because I am working on asp.net site and i want to add some features of jsp so i will design these features in jsp.

Comment: How would you decide which one is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With proper configuration of your server you could probably send requests to either one app or the other. You'd also have to consider how sessions are supposed to be shared between the applications etc.

I'd probably add some base-url to both applications, and use this to make the server redirect the request to the correct app:

- ASP.NET app: your.domain.com/asp/
- J2EE app: your.domain.com/j2ee/

Have a rewrite-cond on the asp/j2ee parts and do what you'd normally do to serve the request.